# How i can get the intersection of lines in java?

Tags: coordinate-system, java

I have two rect lines
Line 1 with coordinate1 and coordinate2
Line 2 with coordinate1 and coordinate2
I need found the intersection of lines.
i tryed using funtions but the result is not real :(
[image]

public class LatLng {
double Lat;
double Lng;

public LatLng(double lat, double lng)
{
this.Lat=lat;
this.Lng=lng;
}

```
public double getLat() {
    return Lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    Lat = lat;
}

public double getLng() {
    return Lng;
}

public void setLng(double lng) {
    Lng = lng;
}
```

}

Example instance: new LatLng(20.582642, -103.389491);

for Line 1; new LatLng(20.593009999338502,-103.3852098167558),
new LatLng(20.593958450190456,-103.38526672545933)

For line 2: new LatLng(20.593349967488706, -103.38568814794907),   new LatLng(20.594009089232976,-103.3838416259881)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which functions did you try? Please add a short code example including two test lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection is one of the easier functions to use. Here is an example using JTS

```
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException;

public class Intersection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


        String wkt1 = "LINESTRING(10 10, 100 100)";
        String wkt2 = "LINESTRING(10 100, 100 10)";

        WKTReader2 reader = new WKTReader2();

        LineString line1 = (LineString) reader.read(wkt1);
        LineString line2 = (LineString) reader.read(wkt2);
        System.out.println(line1);
        System.out.println(line2);
        Point p = (Point) line1.intersection(line2);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

which gives:

```
LINESTRING (10 10, 100 100)
LINESTRING (10 100, 100 10)
POINT (55 55)
```

[image]